# Multiple API keys for Single Android Studio Project

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, android-manifest, google-places-api

I'm using Google Maps API v2 for android and Google Places API, both have different api-keys to be added to manifest, but when i add both the keys, i got multiple-key error.

Is it possible to add two different keys for two different APIs, if not, then what is the possible work around?

```
    <!-- Goolge Maps API Key -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyD****************U6QybngOI" />

   <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyA******************KDaKCEJU" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by using the same GEO API key for both Google Maps v2 and Google Places API, i-e the Geo api-key can be used for both places api and maps api as well.

```
<!-- Goolge Maps API Key -->
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyA******************KDaKCEJU" />    

<!-- Google Places API Key -->
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyA******************KDaKCEJU" />
```

Comment: It is not working for me, I keep getting the error, did you change anything else?

Comment: Finally for me worked by only using the meta-data from geo

Answer (score 3):

You will want to use gradle with [Placeholders](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger#TOC-Placeholder-support).

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="${mapsKey}" />
```

And in your gradle add

```
android {
   buildTypes {
    debug {
      manifestPlaceholders = [ mapsKey:"AIzaSyD****************U6QybngOI"]
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add release and debug keys change your gradle file. You first have to make the API keys in the Google Developer Console.

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
signingConfigs {

}
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.your.app'
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        manifestPlaceholders = [ mapsKey:"AIzaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxvcgdXNA"]
    }
    debug {
        manifestPlaceholders = [ mapsKey:"AIzayyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyC7NA"]
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
}
```

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use multiple key for this purpose. You just have to Enable Both services for the same API key, from the developers console.I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37023930/is-it-possible-to-use-maps-and-place-api-with-same-api-key/37024177?noredirect=1#comment61600298_37024177) answer will guide you through The process.