# Key API SHA-1 certificate fingerprint is wrong

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, sha1

When I used "SHA-1 certificate fingerprint" to Key Api Android function, I added SHA-1 code which I retrieved from my keystore,which is the keystore I used to build my app. By command:

This Picture,which is created by command `keytool -list -v -keystore mystore.keystore:`:

[image]

After, I get SHA1, I use it to provide information for "Restrict usage to your Android apps (Optional)" in Console. However,when I push my app to Google Play Store, My app can't load Google app API's data. My logcat says my SHA1 is wrong, and the SHA1 code needed for my application to work is "**95:53:A3:D5:3E:72:50:A5:F8:AA:19:7B:8A:D0:55:27:D8:E7:A3:F0**" instead of  my SHA1  is "**E4:A5:A3:00:1D:3F:65:17:B4:E8:E8:60:9B:8E:73:6C:90:CC:00:D8**"

I have two question :
where is SHA1 "**95:53:A3:D5:3E:72:50:A5:F8:AA:19:7B:8A:D0:55:27:D8:E7:A3:F0**" and how to create that???

Comment: Have a look at this answer, I believe it addresses your doubt https://stackoverflow.com/a/44672565/5140781

Comment: exactly,thank u very much