# Maps Activity Blank after uploaded to Play Store

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

As mentioned in the title, the Maps Activity shows blank (with Google logo underneath) after I've uploaded the application. I am aware this question has been asked many times but none of the solution is able to resolve my issue.

**This is what I've done so far:**

- Generated Google Maps Release API Key (with SHA-1 signature) following the official guide [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/signup) and placed it under the release/res/values/google_maps_api.xml
- Place the Release API Key hardcoded into the AndroidManifest.xml
- Clean and rebuild the project

**This is the result:**

- The Maps Activity just worked perfectly fine if the app-release.apk is installed manually to the device before upload to the Play Store.
- The Maps Activity shows blank if the app-release.apk after the app-release.apk is uploaded to the Play Store.

**Solution:**

This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44672565/5284152) solved the issue I am facing. The reason the Maps activity shows blank previously because Google Play re-signs the app with the original app signing key I've provided. So just copy the Google SHA-1 and paste it to the console where the Google Map API Key is generated.

Comment: It has to be an API key access thing.  Maybe you need to whitelist an IP address somewhere?

Comment: I'm not really sure cause all the alpha testers seem to encounter the same issue. Can you provide more guide or link so I can go through and attempt it?

Comment: Have you seen the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44672565/5140781? Looks like it explains how to solve your issue.

Comment: @xomena thanks! This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44672565/5284152 solved my question. The main reason it is not working previously because Google Play re-signs the app with the original app signing key I've provided.

Answer (score 3):

If GMap activity is added in any project then there are two google_maps_api.xml. 
One is for Debug and One is for Release. 
[image]

Probably you've entered the key in Debug only as when we add Gmap activity, only google_maps_api.xml opens. So put your key in Release also. How?...see.

1. Click on TODO on the Bottom bar of Android Studio.
   [image]
2. Click on scope Based tab of TODO.
   [image]
3. Now there are two google_maps_api.XML, open each and copy your key
   to XML with no key (YOUR_KEY_HERE).
   [image]
   This also happened with me.

Comment: Thanks for answering. As mentioned in my question, I've placed the release  API key under the release/res/values/google_maps_api.xml

Comment: As you've mentioned "Hard-Coded" so instead of hard-coding, you can still try this.

Comment: After hard-coded it, I've changed it back to the android:value="@string/google_maps_key". You can refer it in my question.

Comment: This answer just saved a life

Answer (score 0):

You have missed adding the permission, try checking by including the permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: I've added the internet permission, but the Maps Activity still blank.