# Google sign in does not work for app when uploaded to Play Store

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am implementing google sign-in in my app.I know i have to generate production ready SHA1 key when releasing the app.I did that using the following command. First i changed my directory where my .jks is stored in terminal and then i used the following command

```
keytool -list -v -keystore SimplyMap.jks
```

I updated the SHA1 in firebase.
After generating signed apk, i transferred my  apk to my mobile through usb and google sign-in works,but as soon as i upload the same apk to Play Store, google sign-in does not work.Can somebody please help me.
FYI,I also generated SHA1 using Android Studio but it didn't worked.
What am i doing wrong?
Just to let you know Google Sign in also works in debug apk.

Comment: I think you should [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44672565/5860777) new policy of Play Store.

Comment: @AndyDeveloper Thanks a lot man.Spend almost a month figuring this out.

Comment: welcome sir. See my answer posted below you can accept the answer so admin can close this question.

Comment: hey!!! check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39318370/google-sign-in-not-working-after-publishing-in-play-store/44330035#44330035

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Here is the answer for why you can't see the Google Map.**

I recently Upload the APK on Google Play store and I faced the same issue after checking the Play Console I found the solution for this problem.

Their is no problem with your key but the problem is with your SHA-1. You signed your APK with your SHA-1 that is fine and then upload the APK it also fine.

But as per the new update for Play Console when you signed your APK with SHA-1 and upload the APK it only signed by you but as per the new update it is also signed by Google Play for more security. Have a look here some part of Google Play section:

> With Google Play App Signing: You sign your app with your upload key.
> Then, Google verifies and removes the upload key signature. Finally,
> Google re-signs the app with the original app signing key you provided
> and delivers your app to the user.

You can refer [Documentation here.](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423)

Now, The Answer of your question is After successfully upload the APK you can see that in the section with Two SHA-1 the **1st SHA-1 is Google created** its own and **2nd SHA-1 is its yours**.

So just copy the Google SHA-1 and paste it to your console where you generate the Google Map API Key.

Comment: hey check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39318370/google-sign-in-not-working-after-publishing-in-play-store/44330035#44330035

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is go to APP signing in play console, there you will SHA-1 in App sign in certificate just copy it and come to firebase console app setting, there you will see an option for adding SHA fingerprint....paste it and it will work.