# Google Map Not Drawing Tiles - Draws Layers

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a very strange issue that has appeared with the Google Maps feature in my app.

The app available for download on the Play store will draw everything just fine.  Rebuilding and installing the app fresh is where the problem is seen.

The odd thing is; the maps view draws, location pins are shown exactly as expected, the "Google" watermark is shown, my custom layers are showing correctly, and pinch and zoom works as expected (I can tell because I can move the layers and scale them).

Tiles are not drawing.  I'm not seeing any road data, any terrain data, or any actual maps data.  I'll attach screenshots.

[image: Zoomed Out]
[image: Zoomed In]

[image: Layers]

Edit:

Okay, I am at a complete loss. I'm actually an iOS developer, so grasping this problem is a big challenge. I'm reading that there are Google maps v1, v2, and v3 (SDK iterations??). I would assume the most current version is v3. I created a new project, added a new API key, and got it to draw a basic map. The API version appears to be 11.0.4 in that test project. The important project I'm having problems with is pretty old.  I inherited it.  I don't know which version it's using (v1, v2, or v3). The dependency is version 8.4.0. The way the API key is set in the problem project is completely different than the new test project.

I do not know what I can do at this point.  Can I simply change the way the API key is set in the old one?  Is the old one even going to work at all, or will I have to re-implement the maps feature?  Is there any way I can easily fix the current feature?  Hoping for a miracle.

Comment: Maybe something similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44672565/5140781

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a problem with your Google API key. You can get more information here:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/8989312/1146533