# Google Sign-in shows ERROR 10 (Logs- Wrong OAuth ), it works in debug app but not in release apk

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

1) I have uploaded apk in play console
2) I have 2 sha1 in firebase console
3) I used Google signing in Google Play console.

Anyone know how to tackle with it?

Comment: I think you need to see [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44672565/5860777)

Comment: you need to add sha-1 key created from your sign apk(release apk) with the credentials that you used to create sign apk

Comment: @AndyDeveloper  I tried this, but whenever i copied it... it shows error something like "sha is already used in this project or other project....."

Answer (score 1):

First thing please create SHA1 using your keystore which you are using for creating a release apk,

After generating SHA1 put in a console and download the google_services.json file again and put in your project after build again, Finally generate Release apk it will.

Comment: I tried this option also... I have added SH1 in firebase console (Now there are 2 SHA1..dont know which is which)... then downloaded the latest google_services.json file and replaced it in project...then released it...but still the problem remains same...

Comment: Can you please post your gradel file code?

Comment: got the solution.... thanks@Andy Developer and @Dhaval Solanki....both of your answers worked for me.. mistakenly i had created duplicate project and it contains SHA1 from play apk signing...

Comment: Good one and Happy to hep you.