# Empty body when trying to get direction between two points using Retrofit

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, retrofit, retrofit2, google-directions-api

I'm using the following code to get the direction between two points on Google Maps:

```
Callback<Direction> directionCallback = new Callback<Direction>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Direction> call, @NonNull Response<Direction> response) {
        if (response != null) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                Direction direction = response.body();
                Log.d("TAG", response.raw());
                if (direction != null) {
                    List<Route> routes = direction.routes;
                    if (routes.size() > 0) {
                        //Get first route
                    } else {
                        Log.d("TAG", "routes.size() = 0");
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", response.errorBody().toString());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<Direction> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
        Log.d("TAG", t.getMessage());
    }
};
directionCall.enqueue(directionCallback);
```

This code works perfectly fine when I run my app from Android Studio on a phone or emulator, however, when I update the app in Google Play, the body of the Retrofit call becomes empty, getting as result:

```
routes.size() = 0
```

If if log `response.raw()`, I get the following response:

```
Response{
  protocol=h2,
  code=200,
  message=,
  url=https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=11.1741765%2C22.6436729&destination=11.189821%2C22.640532&mode=walking&key=LongKey
}
```

If I click on that link, I get the desired JSON file, but the body is empty. No error message. Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: I clicked on the  link, it says I don't have api key. Is the link the error or your call. Better if u show us the response from the link

Comment: @Jason The key that I'm using is correct, but I'm not gonna make it public, as it's for a live project. If I change `LongKey` with the real key, I get the correct page.

Comment: @AlexMamo check this StackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44672565/5180017).

Comment: @Shashanth if the key wasn't there, there would be an error message.